# PHP User Login System not functioning properly

Tags: php, html

For some reason, it displays the encrypted password, and I think I used explode() improperly..
Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
    $teamname   = $_POST['teamname'];
    $teamname   = strtolower($teamname);

    $u_username = $_POST['username'];
    $u_username = strtolower($u_username);
    $key = $_POST['password'];

    // encrypt
    $iv = md5(md5($key));
    $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);

    $file = readfile("teams/$teamname/config.txt","r"); // try to figure out why it's not working
    list($username, $password) = explode(":", $file);

    if ($u_username === $username) 
    {
        if ($password === $u_password) 
        {
            echo "Successfull";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Incorrect Password";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Incorrect Username..";
    }
?>
```

Config.txt
       ivan:bKaeoqHLoPI058d6GJ9IlA4fA/mcoRJ70ZNI3gAczU4=

Comment: You have to compare with $output

Comment: Where does the ':' come from? Do you have more than one user per file? You'll likely require two explodes if you do - one to make an array of users and one per user for username / password.

Comment: I thought explode() needed a separator? The config is laid out like USERNAME:Encrypted Password..

Comment: Yes, explode needs a separator but you didn't show the code where the separator was added to the text string. From the look of your config file you will need to explode once by newline [explode("\n", $file)] which will result in a array of users or other config fields and than explode each user by ":" to get username/password. This is very general since I don't know how your full config is laid out, but you need more than one explode unless what you showed accounts for the entire config.txt

Comment: Also, you might want to use trim() to make sure a rouge whitespace isn't screwing up the comparison. I've seen that many times.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have your password stored as `$output` but you are referencing `$u_password`

```
if ($password === $u_password) {
    echo "Successfull";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect Password";
}
```

should be

```
if ($password === $output) {
    echo "Successfull";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect Password";
}
```

**Alternatively**

```
$output = base64_encode($output);
```

should be

```
$u_password = base64_encode($output);
```

**TEST**

```
if ($u_username == $username)
{
    if ($password == $u_password)
    {
        echo "Successfull";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Password [" . $u_password . '] != [' . $password . ']';
    }
} else {
    echo "Incorrect Username.. [" . $u_username . '] != [' . $username . ']';
}
```

Comment: Then why does it say "Invallid Username" ?

Comment: you didn't tell me that :-), what i said was correct, so it means you have 2 errors somewhere, is the username stored in lowercase? & are you sure it said invalid username, or incorrect username?

Comment: Can you show us the .txt file, so we can check your explode is correct?

Comment: [Added config.txt] Yes, I fixed the password issue to change $password with $output, I also ensured that the password i stored it in lowercase.

Comment: Yes, Danny. The username should be stored in lowercase. I used strtolower() when the user creates they're account, and I double checked the config.txt file to ensure that it was lowercase.

Comment: ok, so what i would do is after the first `<?php` new line, and do `print_r($_POST);` to check that the username & password are being passed as `_POST` correctly, i would also print `$file` to make sure it is getting the contents from the txt too

Comment: Can you do those ^^ and report back with the results please

Comment: We already know that the readfile() is displaying, because it displays [ivan:password] <-- the actual password, and then incorrect username.

Comment: Can you replace your whole if else block with the one i've posted, and then see what the result you get is? This'll help diagnose why it's not matching

Comment: This is my result 1vannn 
1vannn:bKaeoqHLoPI058d6GJ9IlA4fA/mcoRJ70ZNI3gAczU4=Incorrect Username.. [1vannn != 51]

Comment: so there's an issue with your txt file.. instead of readfile use `$file = file_get_contents("teams/$teamname/config.txt");` - not sure where that 51 is coming from

Comment: Danny, I think we've fixed the username issue, now it shows an invalid password.

Comment: I fixed it, the $output wasn't changed to $u_password. Thanks a lot for you're help, Danny.

Comment: @DannyHearnah - 51 is the size of the file. `Readfile()` writes the file to the output stream and returns the number of bytes.

Comment: @mcrumley thanks for that, i did wonder if it was bytes/length of file - good info, wish i'd got the accepted answer for this as the amount of effort when into diagnosing.. and actually gave the correct answer to start with too!